# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'idproveedor' cannot be null

Tags: mysql, laravel, base-de-datos, vue.js, migration

Tengo este problema al momento de querer insertar el registro a mi BD, no entiendo porqué me sale que el valor es nulo, estoy utilizando Laravel con Vuejs
este es mi tabla de base de datos migrada

tabla Base de datos

```
    Schema::create('ingresos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('idproveedor')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('idproveedor')->references('id')->on('proveedores');

        $table->integer('idusuario')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('idusuario')->references('id')->on('users');

        $table->string('tipo_comprobante', 20);
        $table->string('serie_comprobante', 7)->nullable();
        $table->string('num_comprobante', 10);
        $table->dateTime('fecha_hora');
        $table->decimal('impuesto',4,2);
        $table->decimal('total',11,2);
        $table->string('estado',20);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

---

esta es mi Modelo Ingreso

```
class Ingreso extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
    'idproveedor', 'idusuario', 'tipo_comprobante', 'serie_comprobante', 'num_comprobante', 'fecha_hora', 'impuesto', 'total', 'estado'

    ];

    public function usuario(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function proveedor(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Proveedor');
    }
}
```

---

esta es mi función en mi controlador que se llama `IngresoController`

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //if (!$request->ajax()) return redirect('/');
       
       try{

        DB::beginTransaction();
       
        $mytime = Carbon::now('America/Lima');

        $ingresos = new Ingreso();
        $ingresos->idproveedor = $request->idproveedor;
        $ingresos->idusuario = \Auth::user()->id;
        $ingresos->tipo_comprobante = $request->tipo_comprobante;
        $ingresos->serie_comprobante = $request->serie_comprobante;
        $ingresos->num_comprobante = $request->num_comprobante;
        $ingresos->fecha_hora = $mytime->toDateString();
        $ingresos->impuesto = $request->impuesto;
        $ingresos->total = $request->total;
        $ingresos->estado = 'registrado';
        $ingresos->save();

        $detalles = $request->data;
        foreach ($detalles as $ep => $det) {
            $detalle = new DetalleIngreso();
            $detalle->idingreso = $ingresos->id;
            $detalle->idproducto = $det['idproducto'];
            $detalle->cantidad = $det['cantidad'];
            $detalle->precio = $det['precio'];
            $detalle->save();

        }
         
         DB::commit();  
        } catch(Exception $e){

            DB::rollBack();
        }
        
    }
```

---

esta es mi ruta

```
 Route::post('/ingreso/registrar', 'IngresoController@store')->name('ingreso.store');
```

---

y este es mi vuejs

```
 <section>
 
                  <div class="form-group row border">
                      <div class="col-md-9">
                          <div class="form-group select2-border data-border-colo">
                             <label for="">Proveedor(*)</label><br>
                            <!--  <select class=" form-control" style="background-color:#0B1044" v-model="idproveedor">
                               <option value="0" disabled>Seleccione</option>
                               <option v-for="proveedor in arrayProveedor" :key="proveedor.id" :value="proveedor.id"></option>
                              </select>   ---->
                               <div v-if="idproveedor==0 || !idproveedor ">
                              <v-select
                               
                               label="nombre"
                               :options="arrayProveedor"
                               v-model="idproveedor"
                               class=" form-control is-invalid"
                               style="background-color:#0B1044; font-size: 12pt; color: green;"
                               >
                           
                                 
                              </v-select>
                              </div>

                              <div v-else>
                                 <v-select
                          
                               label="nombre"
                               :options="arrayProveedor"
                               v-model="idproveedor"
                               class=" form-control is-valid "
                               style="background-color:#0B1044; font-size: 12pt; color: green;"
                               >    
                              </v-select>
         
                              </div> 
                        
                          </div>
              
                      </div>

                      <div class="col-md-3">
                          <label for="">Impuestos(*)</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" style="background-color:#0B1044" v-model="impuesto">
                      </div>

                      <div class="col-md-4">
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Tipo Comprobante(*)</label>
                            <select class="form-control" v-model="tipo_comprobante" style="background-color:#0B1044">
                               <option value="0" disabled>Seleccione</option>
                               <option value="BOLETA">boleta</option>
                               <option value="FACTURA">factura</option>
                               <option value="TICKET">ticket</option>
                            </select>
                         </div>  
                      </div>

                      <div class="col-md-4">
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Serie Comprobante(*)</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" style="background-color:#0B1044" v-model="serie_comprobante" placeholder="000x">
                         </div>  
                      </div>

                      <div class="col-md-4">
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Numero Comprobante(*)</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" style="background-color:#0B1044" v-model="num_comprobante" placeholder="000x">
                         </div>  ``
                      </div>

                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group row border">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                       <div class="form-group">
                           <label>Productos</label>
                           <div class="form-inline">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" @keyup.enter="buscarProducto()" style="background-color:#0B1044" v-model="codigo" placeholder="busqueda de productos">
                              <button @click="abrirModal()" class="btn btn-primary">....</button>
                              <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" v-model="producto" style="background-color:#0B1044">
                           </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2">
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Precio:</label>
                          <input type="number"  step="any" placeholder="0.0" class="form-control"  style="background-color:#0B1044" v-model="precio">

                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2">
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Cantidad:</label>
                          <input type="number"  step="any" placeholder="2" class="form-control" style="background-color:#0B1044"  v-model="cantidad">

                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button @click="agregarDetalle()" class="btn btn-success btnagregar">
                             <i class="feather icon-plus-circle"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group row border">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                       <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm">
                          <thead> 
                            <tr>
                               <th>Opciones</th>
                               <th>Productos</th>
                               <th>Precio</th>
                               <th>Cantidad</th>
                               <th>Subtotal</th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody v-if="arrayDetalle.length">
                            <tr  v-for="(detalle,index) in arrayDetalle" :key="detalle.id" style="background-color: #0B1044;">
                               <td>
                                 <button @click="eliminarDetalle(index)" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                                   <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                                 </button>
                               </td>
                               <td v-text="detalle.producto"></td>
                               <td>
                                 <input v-model="detalle.precio" type="number" value="3" class="form-control"  >
                               </td>
                               <td>
                                 <input v-model="detalle.cantidad" type="number" value="2" class="form-control" 
                                  >
                               </td>
                               <td>
                                 {{(detalle.precio*detalle.cantidad).toFixed(2)}}
                               </td>
                            </tr>
                             <tr style="background-color:#4E54A0">
                              <td colspan="4" align="right"><strong> Total Parcial:</strong></td>
                              <td>$ {{total=calcularTotal.toFixed(2)}}</td>
                            </tr>
                           
                            <tr style="background-color:#4E54A0">
                              <td colspan="4" align="right"><strong> Total Impuesto:</strong></td>
                              <td>$ {{totalimpuesto=(total*impuesto).toFixed(2)}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr style="background-color:#4E54A0">
                           <td colspan="4" align="right"><strong> Total Neto:</strong></td>
                              <td>$ {{totalparcial=calcularTotalneto.toFixed(2)}}</td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                          <tbody v-else>
                             <tr>
                               <td colspan="5" align="center">
                                No hay articulos agregados
                               </td>
                             </tr>
                          
                            
                          </tbody>
                       </table>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group row ">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @click="ocultarDetalle">Cerrar</button>
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="registrarIngreso()">Registrar Compra</button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
       
                </section>
                 

<script>

export default {
     
        
        data (){
            return {
                ingreso_id: 0,
                idproveedor: 0,
                nombre_proveedores:'',
                tipo_comprobante : '0',
                serie_comprobante : '',
                num_comprobante : '',
                impuesto : 0.18,
                total : 0.0,
                totalimpuesto:0.0,
                totalparcial:0.0,
                arrayIngreso : [],
                arrayDetalle:[],
                listado: 1,
                modal : 0,
                tituloModal : '',
                tipoAccion : 0,
                arrayProveedor:[],
                arrayProducto:[],
                idproducto:0,
                codigo:'',
                producto:'',
                precio:0,
                cantidad:0
}
methods{

                   registrarIngreso(){
                let me = this;


                axios.post('/ingreso/registrar',{
                   
                  
                    'idproveedor': this.idproveedor,
                    'tipo_comprobante': this.tipo_comprobante,
                    'serie_comprobante': this.serie_comprobante,
                    'num_comprobante': this.num_comprobante,
                    'total': this.total,
                     'data': this.arrayDetalle


                }).then(function (response) {
                
                    
                    $("#example").dataTable().fnDestroy();
                    me.listarIngreso();
                    me.ocultarDetalle();
                  
                      
                    me.idproveedor=0;
                    me.tipo_comprobante='BOLETA';
                    me.serie_comprobante='';
                    me.num_comprobante='';
                    me.impuesto=0.18;
                    me.total=0.0;
                    me.idproducto=0;
                    me.producto='';
                    me.cantidad=0;
                    me.precio=0;
                    me.arrayDetalle=[];

                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            },
     mounted() {
            //this.listarIngreso();
        this.selectProveedor();
      
        }
        //fin de mounted
    }//f
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola Kevin en tu migracion tienes mal definido el campo, en laravel 6 o 7 cambio un poco la convencion de esto, te muestro
Tienes esto

```
 $table->integer('idusuario')->unsigned();
```

Solo cambialo a

```
$table->unisgnedBigInteger('idusuario');
```

En caso de que no funcione:

Intenta con:

```
$table->bigInteger('idusuario')->unsigned();
```

Comment: me sale que unsignedBigInteger no existe

Comment: que version de laravel tienes?

Comment: ya solucione el problema, primero me faltaba agregar mi variable impuesto y segundo estaba enviando un objeto y había que enviar en cambio, una propiedad de ese objeto

Answer (score 0):

Cambia esto:

```
$table->integer('idusuario')->unsigned();
```

Por esto:

```
$table->integer('idusuario')->unsigned()->nullable();
```

Saludos,

Comment: Hola Adolfo, debes añadir algo más de información, ¿qué es lo que hace el cambio?¿cómo soluciona el problema?